# Get entire packets size in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

Is there a way to show the size of all of the packets received in Wireshark?

For example, if I have 10 packets received and the size of each packet is 1 KB, then Wireshark would display: 10 KB.

Answer (score 0):

See the Wireshark [Statistics menu](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUseStatisticsMenuSection.html):
[Summary window](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatSummary.html)
Packet Lengths... may also be helpful.